How to get the FTP endpoint using Azure SDK in Blazor?
I am able to get the username and password, but I cannot get the HostName, which is the FTP endpoint visible on the Azure Portal.
 var ftpPublishingData = await _webSite.GetPublishingCredentialsAsync(WaitUntil.Completed);

 var username = ftpPublishingData.Value.Data.PublishingUserName;
 var password = ftpPublishingData?.Value.Data.PublishingPassword;

I need to get the FTP endpoint because I need it to upload files to Azure App Service using WinSCP. I am doing all of this in Blazor because I want to automate everything, so I need to obtain the FTP endpoint programmatically.

Are you able to get username and password in Blazor WASM?

I am getting this error in Blazor WASM App authentication failed: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.

Can you please share your .csproj file and complete code of GetPublishingCredentialsAsync

You can use Azure CLI command to get the credentials az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name BlazorFTP --resource-group RGName --query "[?ends_with(profileName, 'FTP')].{profileName: profileName, publishUrl: publishUrl, userName: userName, userPWD: userPWD}"

I have tried to get the FTP Credentials in Blazor WASM and Blazor Server, got the below error while authenticating.
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.AppService;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FtpEndpoint
{
    private readonly ArmClient _arm;
    private readonly string _rgName;
    private readonly string _AppName;
    private readonly string _subId;

    public FtpEndpoint(string subId, string rgName, string AppName)
    {
        _subId = subId;
        _rgName = rgName;
        _AppName = AppName;

        var cred = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        _arm = new ArmClient(cred);

    }

    public async Task<string> GetFtpEndpointAsync()
    {
        var resId = $"/subscriptions/{_subId}/resourceGroups/{_rgName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{_AppName}";
        var webResource = _arm.GetWebSiteResource(new ResourceIdentifier(resId));
        var app = await webResource.GetAsync();
        var ftpHost = app.Value.Data.HostNames
            .FirstOrDefault(host => host.EndsWith(".ftp.azurewebsites.net")) ?? "No FTP hostname found";
        return ftpHost;
    }
}

With DefaultAzureCredential
Error: AzureCliCredential authentication failed: System.Diagnostics.Process is not supported on this platform. - 

With InteractiveBrowserCredential
Error: InteractiveBrowserCredential authentication failed: System.Net.Sockets is not supported on this platform.


Even I tried it by authenticating the App with Azure AD.

Refer this SOThread which address the same issue.

I need it to upload files to Azure App Service using WinSCP

As an alternative you can get the credentials using Azure CLI.
I have taken references from this MSDoc
az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name BlazorFTP --resource-group HarshithVeeramalla --query "[?ends_with(profileName, 'FTP')].{profileName: profileName, publishUrl: publishUrl, userName: userName, userPWD: userPWD}"

Output:
[
  {
    "profileName": "BlazorFTP - FTP",
    "publishUrl": "ftp://****.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot",
    "userName": "BlazorFTP\\$BlazorFTP",
    "userPWD": "******"
  }
]


